# UIBezier curve becomes blurry when resizing view

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, scale, blur, uibezierpath

I have a collection view whose cell size the user can change. The collection view has a template cell that contains a `UIImageView` in the bottom-right corner. This image view scales proportionally with the collection view cell. In this image view I do some custom drawing at different times using `UIBezierPath` objects.

If I draw the image and the user changes the cell size, the image is proportionally scaled and interpolated, becoming slightly blurry. It's as if the image is being cached and re-used, but that's not what I want. I want the each cell to have to redraw its the curves in its image view so that they're sharp and not blurry.

Here's an example of how I'm drawing in the `UIImageView`:

```
//ImageView.m
//Draw a custom image (forgive the magic numbers)
-(void)drawImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, self.bounds.size.width-2, self.bounds.size.height-2)];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    [circle setLineWidth:self.bounds.size.width/44.0f];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [circle fill];
    [circle stroke];

    UIBezierPath *checkmark = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    float r = self.bounds.size.width / 160.0f;
    [checkmark moveToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0f*r, 40.0f*r)];
    [checkmark addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(120.0f*r,120.0f*r)];
    [checkmark moveToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0f*r, 120.0f*r)];
    [checkmark addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(120.0f*r, 40.0f*r)];
    [checkmark setLineWidth:self.bounds.size.width/22.0f];
    [checkmark stroke];
    [self setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Here's how I change the cell size:

```
//ViewController.m 
//The user chooses a cell size from a UISegmentedControl.
-(IBAction)selectedSegmentIndexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    int i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    int p = 2.0f*(4-i);
    int s = (320-p*i)/(i+1);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(s,s);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = p;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = p;
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using notifications to achieve my goal of redrawing the image.

When the layout is done animating I post a notification:

```
//ViewController.m 
//The user chooses a cell size from a UISegmentedControl.
-(IBAction)selectedSegmentIndexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    int i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    int p = 2.0f*(4-i);
    int s = (320-p*i)/(i+1);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(s,s);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = p;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = p;
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout 
                                        animated:YES 
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished{
                                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"collectionViewLayoutDidChange" object:nil];
                                      }];
}
```

The imageView observes the notification and redraws:

```
//ImageView.m
//
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveNotification:) name:@"collectionViewLayoutDidChange" object:nil];
}

//I also added the following method prototype to ImageView.h
-(void)didReceiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"collectionViewLayoutDidChange"]){
        [self drawImage];
        return;
    }
}
```